# How to put extra files in Android APK with Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I want to add a text file to my APK root. This file will not be used in the application but it will stay there for manual extraction of the APK.

I tried to put it into the root of the project in Eclipse but it didn't include that file in the APK. I don't want to put it into assets folder. Can't I put it to the root?

Comment: No. Use the Assets folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files that are not put into any of the main directories of your android project will NOT be included in your apk. You MUST put the file in the assets so it can be accessed within the application as an external resource/file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the assets folder.
According to [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

> assets/
>       This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data.